# Problems with versioning

Tags: arcgis-10.0, postgis, arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I have 5 PostgreSQL_PostGIS database in my company and i conneting on them through ArcSDE. Four of database work correctly, only with one i have i realy big problem. When i make two versions of database, and i edit data in one version, reconcile and post on DEFAULT version, database do some kinde of automaticly reconcile on second version, and i see all the changes in second version before i do reconcile. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: The feature class you are reconciling, do you have "Move Edits to Base" enabled?  You can check this in the feature class properties dialog.